# Conditional Where when using Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

I have a working procedure to show the report for given range of period. 
The below proc finds all the bookings for the given period of time and shows for each month group

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSummaryOverviewReport] (
    @StartDate SMALLDATETIME = NULL
    ,@EndDate SMALLDATETIME = NULL
    ,@IncludeVAT BIT = 0
    ,@AddedAfter SMALLDATETIME
    ,@HasObservation BIT = 0
    ,@IncludeCancelledBooking BIT = 0
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN
        SELECT YEAR(StartTime) [Year]
            ,MONTH(StartTime) [Month]
            ,COUNT(BookingId) [BookingCount]
            ,SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN IsVAT = 1
                        AND @IncludeVAT = 1
                        THEN (Price / 100) * 80
                    ELSE Price
                    END) AS TotalPrice
            ,PaidCount = sum(CASE 
                    WHEN B.PaymentStatus = 'FullyPaid'
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END)
            ,PaidSum = sum(CASE 
                    WHEN B.PaymentStatus = 'FullyPaid'
                        THEN (
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN IsVAT = 1
                                        AND @IncludeVAT = 1
                                        THEN (Price / 100) * 80
                                    ELSE Price
                                    END
                                )
                    ELSE 0
                    END)
            ,C.CategoryId
            ,CategoryName
        FROM Category c
        LEFT JOIN Booking B ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
        WHERE B.AddedDateTime > @AddedAfter
            AND ISNULL(B.IsCancelled, 0) = 0
            AND (
                (
                    B.StartTime BETWEEN @StartDate
                        AND @EndDate
                    )
                OR (
                    B.StartTime BETWEEN @StartDate
                        AND @EndDate
                    )
                )
            AND (
                @HasObservation = 0
                OR B.PatientID IN (
                    SELECT PatientID
                    FROM PatientXObservation O
                    WHERE ObservationId IN (
                            1
                            ,2
                            ,4
                            )
                    )
                )
        GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime)
            ,MONTH(StartTime)
            ,C.CategoryId
            ,CategoryName
        ORDER BY 1
            ,2
            ,CategoryName
    END
END
```

Now we want to add a filter **@IncludeCancelledBooking** parameter. So user can select whether to show cancelled bookings or not. As of now the procedure ignores the cancelled booking and shows only non cancelled booking..

I couldn't able to find out how to add this condition while grouping the records. **I need to use AND ISNULL(B.IsCancelled, 0) = 0 based on @IncludeCancelledBooking**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the logic that you want?

```
(@IncludeCancelled <> 'Y' OR Booking ISNULL(B.IsCancelled, 0) = 0)
```

Comment: `OR Booking ISNULL(B.IsCancelled, 0) = 0` in this `Booking` is alias ? I couldnt get by seeing how it will work. Anyway I will try changing the proc and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me. `AND (@IncludeCancelledBooking <> 0 OR ISNULL(B.IsCancelled, 0) = 0)`

Answer (score 0):

If `IsCancelled` is also a `BIT`(like `@IncludeCancelled`), then you could use:

```
 AND ISNULL(B.IsCancelled, 0) IN (0, @IncludeCancelled)
```

If `@IncludeCancelled` is 0, then this is effectively the same logic you have now (i.e. `= 0`). If `@IncludeCancelled` is 1, then this includes where `IsCancelled` = 1.

Comment: How about using `AND ISNULL(B.IsCancelled, 0) = @IncludeCancelled`?

Comment: If `@IncludeCancelled` is 1, then you will *only* get cancelled bookings. If you use `IN`, you'll get cancelled and non-cancelled bookings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing value 1 for the variable @IncludeCancelled for including the cancelled booking. Then change the WHERE condition like below.

```
   AND ISNULL(B.IsCancelled,0)= 
        CASE WHEN @IncludeCancelled=1 
                    THEN ISNULL(B.IsCancelled,0)
                     ELSE 0 END
```